# How do I get a menu for searching a certain page in search engines?

Tags: html, search

When you look up "post office" in Google, the first link you get is for the US postoffice, and there is a nice menu below it that describes the main menu in the Post office website.

What kind of HTML directives do I need to put into a page in order to get such a menu in search engines?

Another question: how can I verify quickly it works, once I add the HTML directives? Will I have to wait for the next crawl of a search engine to see what it would look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webmaster.google.com is a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

There is no options as such. If your website is well optimized and got good traffic, google does it automatically.

I run a website http://onlinemacha.com for students who wish to study abroad. For the past one month, when the keyword onlinemacha is searched for, google results all menus under the root. 
[image]